# Incorrect JSON format with Jackson and JaxB Annotation Module

Tags: java, json, jaxb, jackson

Very weird problem with Jackson and JaxB Annotation. See the issue with incorrect JSON format.

```
public interface All {
}

@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=AnyAdapter.class, type=Any.class)
public interface Any {
    public boolean isKnown();
}

@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=AnyAdapter.class, type=Any.class)
public abstract class Known implements Any {
    @Override
    @XmlTransient
    public boolean isKnown() {
        return false;
    }
    public Known(String type) {
        super();
        this.type = type;
    }
    String type;

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public abstract void validate();
}

@XmlRootElement
public class Resource extends Known implements All{
    public Resource(Integer resourceId, String resourceName) {
        super("Resource");
        this.resourceId = resourceId;
        this.resourceName = resourceName;
    }
    public Integer getResourceId() {
        return resourceId;
    }
    public void setResourceId(Integer resourceId) {
        this.resourceId = resourceId;
    }
    public String getResourceName() {
        return resourceName;
    }
    public void setResourceName(String resourceName) {
        this.resourceName = resourceName;
    }
    Integer resourceId;
    String  resourceName;
    @Override
    public void validate() {
    }
}

@XmlRootElement
public class ResourceList extends Known{
    public ResourceList(String name) {
        super("ResourceList");
        this.name = name;
    }
    List<All> resourceList;
    String name;
        @XmlElements({ 
            @XmlElement(name="resource", type=Resource.class), 
        })
    public List<All> getResourceList() {
        return resourceList;
    }
    public void setResourceList(List<All> resourceList) {
        this.resourceList = resourceList;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void validate() {
    }

}

public class JacksonJaxbAdapterImpl {

    public ObjectMapper initializeJackson() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
        mapper.configure(MapperFeature.SORT_PROPERTIES_ALPHABETICALLY, true);
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);

        // Need to use JaxB Annotation.
        JaxbAnnotationModule module = new JaxbAnnotationModule();
        mapper.registerModule(module);

        SimpleModule mySimpleModule = new SimpleModule();
        mySimpleModule.addSerializer(Long.class, new ToStringSerializer());
        mySimpleModule.addSerializer(Double.class, new ToStringSerializer());
        mapper.registerModule(mySimpleModule);

        return mapper;
    }

    public void writeObject(Object target, Writer writer, boolean isPretty) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = initializeJackson();
        try {
            if(isPretty) {
                mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValue(writer,target);
            } else {
                mapper.writeValue(writer,target);
            }
        } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
         } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
         } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
         }
    }

}

public class JacksonJaxbAdapterTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JacksonJaxbAdapterTest test = new JacksonJaxbAdapterTest();

        ResourceList report = test.makeObject();
        StringWriter jacksonWriter = new StringWriter();

        JacksonJaxbAdapterImpl jacksonMainClass = new JacksonJaxbAdapterImpl();
        jacksonMainClass.initializeJackson();
        jacksonMainClass.writeObject(report, jacksonWriter, true);

        System.out.println(jacksonWriter);
    }

    ResourceList makeObject() {
        Resource primary = new Resource(12,"primary");
        Resource secondary = new Resource(13, "secondary");

        List<All> listofRes = new ArrayList<All>();
        listofRes.add(primary);
        listofRes.add(secondary);

        ResourceList report = new ResourceList("Daily");
        report.setResourceList(listofRes);

        return report;
    }
}
```

The JSON Output is with an extra unwanted "resource" tag.

```
{
  "name" : "Daily",
  "resourceList" : [ {
    "resource" : {
      "resourceId" : 12,
      "resourceName" : "primary",
      "type" : "Resource"
    }
  }, {
    "resource" : {
      "resourceId" : 13,
      "resourceName" : "secondary",
      "type" : "Resource"
    }
  } ],
  "type" : "ResourceList"
}
```

Remove the @XmlElements Tag (in ResourceList.java) and leave it with @XmlElement tag only- the JSON becomes perfect without the "resource" tag. @XmlElement(name="resource", type=Resource.class)

```
{
  "name" : "Daily",
  "resource" : [ {
    "resourceId" : 12,
    "resourceName" : "primary",
    "type" : "Resource"
  }, {
    "resourceId" : 13,
    "resourceName" : "secondary",
    "type" : "Resource"
  } ],
  "type" : "ResourceList"
}
```

Any Suggestion?

Comment: Does your solution work or not? What is your question?

Comment: I cant get rid of the @XMLElements Tag as Resource.java, ResourceList.java are auto generated. How do I get a perfect JSON with XmlElements tag?

Comment: In your question you write "Remove the @XmlElements Tag". Can you do this or not? Why?

Comment: I cant do it because of 2 reasons- first this code is auto-generated. Secondly- I need to have multiple XmlElement in the actual code example-       @XmlElements({ 
            @XmlElement(name="resource", type=Resource.class),@XmlElement(name="person", type=Person.class), 
        })

Comment: If `ResourceList.java` is generated, I have no idea.

Comment: I need the XmlElements tag actually. Wondering why Jackson is generating the extra Tag?